# str() function in python3 vs python2

Tags: python, utf-8, unicode-string

We've all used python to pass binary arguments to C/C++ programs. for example:

`python2 -c "print '\xf0'" | ./sample_binary` gives `f00a` hex values to `./sample_binary`. This functionality is useful to me specially when crafting custom inputs for overflow exploitation.

Question is, how can I achieve the same functionality with Python3? The same command gives a different result:

`python3 -c "print('\xf0')"`: this one gives `c3b0 0a` instead of the desired value which is `f00a`. I know this is related to the `str()` function since python3 is UTF-8 by default. Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: The best way to write raw-bytes to standard out in Python 3 is to use `sys.stdout.buffer.write` and use `bytes` objects (which would be equivalent to Python 2 `str` objects).

Comment: So in this case, use `python3 -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\xf0\n')"` note, you have to add the newline charaxcter manually.